# Sharing Username Between Two Public Classes In Separate JAVA Files

Tags: java, string, text, sharing

I got Two JAVA Files and Two Public Classes In them I take the username in File1.java and then need to work with it in File2.java so basically i need to take the username from user in File1.java and then pass it to File2.java for processing.

Now i am done with the part of Taking Username From User using File1.java but dont know how to give it to the File2.java for processing. This is how i take username from user in File1.java and store it into the variable user. Now i need to move this user data to File2.java.

```
    String user = jTextField1.getText();
```

So please help me with passing username data from File1.java to File2.java

Comment: Don't think in files with Java. Think in terms of objects and the answer simply becomes: instantiate a new object and pass it the string (either in the constructor or through a public accessor).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to pass it to `File2.java`, so assuming that you have something like so:

```
public class File2
{
    ...
    //Constructor
    public File2(...)
    ...
}
```

You would need to change it like so:

```
public class File2
{
    ....
    String userName = "";
    public File2(...String userName...)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

And call it like so (from your `File1` class):

```
String user = jTextField1.getText();
...
File2 file2 = new File2(..., user, ...);
```

Alternatively, instead of passing the `userName` field, you can pass an instance of `File1` to your `File2` class and expose whatever fields you want to access through `Field2` by creating the appropriate `get` methods in your `File1` class. This usually comes in handy when you need to access more than one field.

Comment: When i use this suggestion i get a 'null' in String variable in File2.java, because a new instance of File1.java should render the jTextField1 null right??

Comment: @user2078258: You would need to initialize the field and put a value in it in File1.java. Usually, the user presses a button or some other event which causes you to load File2.java.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass it as a `parameter` to a method present in `File2` class or you can have a getter method for `user` in `File1` class and create a new instance of `File1` class in `File2` class and call the `getter` using that instance.

**In File1**

```
new File2().doSomethingMethod(user);
```

**In File2**

```
public void doSomethingMethod(String user){
    //user has the value you wanted to pass.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sharing values across classes, you can make the variables as instance variables and have setters and getters to access them.

In your case, make `user` as a private instance variable of your class `File1` and then in your `File2` class, you can do something like :

```
public void someMethod(File1 f1Object){

  String s = f1Object.getUser();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

File1.java and File2.java are *filenames*, they don't really matter for what you're discussing.  What's more important is that you have two java classes.  Talk about their class names instead of the filenames.

Hopefully, what you also have are two (or more) java **objects**, do you?  That is, instances of those classes.

If the **object** of the second class needs to do some processing, then you need to define a method in this second class, like this:

```
public void doSomeProcessing(String userName)
{
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
object2.doSomeProcessing(jTextField1.getText());
```

But please, give the files, classes, objects and methods meaningful names!